# Swift, node moving alone

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, sknode

I am trying to use `SKNode` in `overlaySKScene` in a `SCNView`.
But when I set the property `isPlaying` of the `SCNView` to true, my `SKNodes` are just going down.

This is my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
sceneView.isPlaying = true;
sceneView.loops = true;
sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
sceneView.overlaySKScene = SKScene(size: SceneView.frame.size)
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.shouldEnableEffects = true
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.backgroundColor = SKColor.clear
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.blendMode = .alpha
let node = myFunctionToDrawCircle()
node.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
sceneView.overlaySKScene?.addChild(node)
```

I linked the `sceneView` from a `SCNView` in the storyboard like others component.

Comment: What is the expect behaviour? What do you want to achieve?